# Custom 500 error page using JSF - is the full error message available?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, error-handling, web.xml

In my web.xml the 500 error is handled by a JSF page:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errorpage.html</location>
</error-page>
```

If the container handles a 500 error and calls this JSF page, is there a request parameter or body content in the request which contains the full error message?

So for example if I use this code in a Servlet to provide a error description with the 500 error:

```
response.sendError(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR, "Some error message");
```

is there a standard way to get the text "Some error message" from the request?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's available as request attribute with the key of [`RequestDispatcher#ERROR_MESSAGE`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#ERROR_MESSAGE) which is [`"javax.servlet.error.message"`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.ERROR_MESSAGE). So, this should do:

```
<p>The error message is: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}</p>
```

*(note: I'm assuming that you're using Facelets; for JSP you'd have to put it in `<h:outputText>`)*

Comment: I am trying this and I can only get `javax.servlet.error.exception`, but not `javax.servlet.error.message`, `javax.servlet.error.exception_type` or any of the rest. What could be the reason?